# ExtJs How to Loading data into form panel from store/model

Tags: extjs, extjs4

i'm really new to extjs 4. im try to load default value form load as bellow

```
    launch: function() {
       Ext.create('panelid', {renderTo: 'form'});
      var form = this.up('panelid').getForm();
      var model = Ext.getCmp('modelid');
      form.loadRecord(model);
   }
```

that not work form me that gave to me `undefined form`

this my view class

```
Ext.define('panelid', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',

    alternateClassName: [
        'confpanel'
    ],
    requires: [
        'Ext.container.Container',
        'Ext.form.field.File',
        'Ext.button.Button'
    ],

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        Ext.applyIf(me, {
            items: [


                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    itemId: 'NAME_2',
                    fieldLabel: 'SDFA',
                    name: 'NAME_2'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    handler: function(button, e) {
                        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                        if(form.isValid()){
                            form.submit({
                                url: 'AA?submit=true'
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    itemId: 'btnSave',
                    text: 'Save'
                }
            ]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }

});
```

my store userClassName name is 'storeid' and my model userClassName is `modelid` this very simple question but it really hard to understand data communication in between server-client. please help to me this simple question

Comment: I would suggest you define your items inline with the rest of the class rather than trying to set it inside `initComponent`. You don't gain anything by it.  As far as your error is concerned, I think you need to set an `alias` to your view. The command `up('panelid')` doesn't know what `panelid` is. Add the following: `..., alias: 'widget.panelid'` after the `extend`.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of errors on your code:

renderTo should only be used with Elements and not components.
E.g. Ext.getBody() or a div id on your html page
For containers you should use applyTo.

And a model is not a Component. You cannot use getCmp to get the model reference.

You will have to define it the same way you defined the panel and then use the name you specified there as a reference.

Check the sencha documents on how to do all this. Its very well explained there.